# Insertar la fecha/día del sistema en la aplicación JAVA

Tags: java, date

¿Como podría añadir la clase o un método `Calendar` para añadir la fecha/hora del sistema a mi aplicación **Java**?
Sé que existe la clase `Calendar` la cual te da la fecha y hora del sistema.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Fechas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Instanciamos el objeto Calendar
        //en fecha obtenemos la fecha y hora del sistema
        Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
        //Obtenemos el valor del año, mes, día,
        //hora, minuto y segundo del sistema
        //usando el método get y el parámetro correspondiente
        int año = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes = fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hora = fecha.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minuto = fecha.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int segundo = fecha.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        System.out.println("Fecha Actual: "
                           + dia + "/" + (mes+1) + "/" + año);
        System.out.printf("Hora Actual: %02d:%02d:%02d %n",
                                              hora, minuto, segundo);
    }
}
```

Mi problema viene a la hora de integrarlo en un `JMenuBar`, ¿debería añadir un `label`(el cual mostraría estos datos) en mi `JMenuBar`?

Os dejo la imagen descriptiva: https://s24.postimg.org/4yjyqkxol/image.png

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que estas teniendo? Obtener la hora actual del sistema o integrarlo al JMenuBar

Comment: Obtener la fecha ya la tengo con esa función, mi problema es integrarlo al JMenuBar, como puse al final del código.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `JMenuBar`? La utilidad de ese componente es: _"When the user selects a JMenu object, its associated JPopupMenu is displayed, allowing the user to select one of the JMenuItems on it"_ y no creo que quieras seleccionar nada, sólo mostrar la fecha.

Comment: ¿qué debería de usar... un JPanel de poca altura debajo del todo donde en el margen derecho pongo un JLabel con esos datos?

Comment: Es difícil de decir sin saber qué quieres hacer exactamente con tu interfaz, pero si quieres simplemente poner una barra arriba del todo con un `JMenuBar` y un `JLabel` puedes usar un único `JPane` donde añadas los dos con un Layout que te quede bien para lo que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

yo lo haría así:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
public class Fechas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
        fecha.setTime(new Date());

    int año = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mes = fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dia = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hora = fecha.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minuto = fecha.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int segundo = fecha.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    System.out.println("Fecha Actual: " + dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + año);
    System.out.printf("Hora Actual: %02d:%02d:%02d %n", hora, minuto, segundo);
    System.out.println("Otra forma de Fecha Actual: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(fecha.getTime()));
    System.out.println("Otra forma de Hora Actual: " + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa").format(fecha.getTime()));
}
```

}